# Click on dynamic elements in jquery module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have short module for my submenu created in jquery. I have added click event which should work even if menu is dynamically created, but it isn't. I have tried to bind click directly to submenu and it's working. Anyone has idea why this line of code doesn't work?

```
$(document).on('click', class_btn_submenu, toggle);
```

but this one works?

```
$(class_btn_submenu).on('click', toggle);
```

full module:

```
var Submenu = (function() {
    var class_active = 'active';
    var class_btn_submenu = '#account-sil';
    var holder_menu = $('#user-submenu');

    var open = function() {
        holder_menu.addClass(class_active);
    };

    var close = function() {
        holder_menu.removeClass(class_active);
    };

    var toggle = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(holder_menu.hasClass(class_active)) {
            close();
        } else {
            open();
        }
    };

    $(document).on('click', class_btn_submenu, toggle);
    $(class_btn_submenu).on('click', toggle);

    return this;
})();
```

PS: I don't have both events there, it's just to display where I'm testing them.

Comment: You're adding the menu dynamically but using an `id`? (`#account-sil`)  Do all your submenus have the same ID?  Have you tried with a class?

Comment: Please can you show us some of your HTML that this is intended to run against?  Also you mention that you don't have your events where you have put them, I would say that where you call your `on()` events to hook them up is imperative to ensure that this code works correctly.

Comment: @freedomn-m it's just one menu which is showing or hiding.

Comment: @Luke events are there where I put them, but there is only one event not both of them. I want it to work with document.on click so it's working with dynamic menu or with static menu, both cases.

Comment: I'm testing this against static menu, it's already in html, not dynamically added and it's not working.

Comment: Please can you post the HTML block then too :))))

Comment: I understand why you want to see HTML but there is no point. That HTML isn't important in this case, I have tested both ways with console.log and one is working and second one isn't working.